# Ubuntu Setup Low Disk Space

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, crash

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and during the process it crashes saying there are 20-40 MB (it changes every time) of free space in my disk. I don't know why it says that since I have formatted the HDD and made the partitions myself with the Ubuntu installer.
Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: How did you format it?

Comment: 20-40mb?  MB???  What size partitions have you setup?  Ubuntu installed needs GB not MB

Comment: which install option are you using?

Comment: I have formatted it using a Windows 7 CD. And I'm installing it directly though I will try to install it from "Try Ubuntu without installing it".

Comment: Partition sizes are: Swap - 4gb, Root - 50 Gb and the remaining space is for /home. I have a 1 TB HDD

Comment: if the partitions are made before installing, you have to select "Something Else" and tell the installer which partitions to use for what,

Comment: Please update your question with output of `df -h`.